# "fold" in Haskell?

Tags: haskell

Write a function of higher order `atEach f xs` applying the default function `f` to each element of the list `xs`.

```
atEach succ [1 to 5] = [2,3,4,5,6]
atEach length ["Haskell", "go", "forward"] = [7,5,8]
```

Comment: Why not `atEach length ["Haskell", "go", "forward"] = [7, 2, 7]`? If so, you are being asked to rewrite the standard `map` function. **What have you tried?**

Comment: @AntonGuryanov Please don't do the OP's homework for him, he will not learn. (Help him: yes; do it for him: no.)

Comment: @dave4420 OK, deleted my comment :)

Comment: Yeah, this just looks like your standard `map` function

Comment: yes, it's for my homework and I would like concrete assistance

Comment: https://docs.google.com/document/d/1ky6tSD5Z63UI2xJx5beZvdLgcva2iWZeDP5bnwYJ-wc/edit?usp=sharing  How to I am writing the homework, I was wondering if you could help me

Comment: possible duplicate of [How would you define map and filter using foldr in Haskell?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5726445/how-would-you-define-map-and-filter-using-foldr-in-haskell)

Answer (score 5):

As dave4420 already pointed out, your `atEach` seems to be the standard `map` function (please clarify if not). If this is the case, you have different ways to implement it, e.g.:

```
-- direct recursion
atEach _ [] = []
atEach f (x:xs) = ??? 

-- list comprehension
atEach f xs = [??? | x <- xs]

--using a fold
atEach f = foldr ??? []
```

I don't want to spoil the fun, so you can try to fill out the `???`.