# Filtering for values in Haskell

Tags: haskell

I've been doing some Haskell exercises from a Haskell book, and one of the tasks is for me to filter for values of a certain type and return them as a list.

```
import Data.Time

data Item = DbString String
          | DbNumber Integer
          | DbDate UTCTime
          deriving (Eq, Ord, Show)


database :: [Item]
database =
  [
    DbDate (UTCTime (fromGregorian 1911 5 1) (secondsToDiffTime 34123)),
    DbNumber 9001,
    DbString "Hello World!",
    DbDate (UTCTime (fromGregorian 1921 5 1) (secondsToDiffTime 34123))
  ]
```

That's the code I am given to work with, and for my first task:

`Write a function that filters for DbDate values and returns a list of the UTCTime values inside them.` The template for the function is:

```
filterDate :: [Item] -> [UTCTime]
filterDate = undefined
```

What I have to use here are folds since that is the matter concerned here.

I looked up the `Data.Time` module on Hoogle and that didn't really help since I couldn't understand how to interact with the module. Maybe I'm looking at this from a wrong perspective because I don't think it has something to do with the `filter` function, and I don't think it has something to do with type-casting neither `::`.

How do I get UTCTime values, and how do I filter for them?

Comment: I said "What makes you think you should be using a fold? The question doesn't imply that: I read it as saying you need to filter the list of `Item` to return `DbDate` values and then unpack the `UTCTime` from each value." ... but I think I'm seeing the light now. You can implement a filter as a fold by walking across your import list and concatenating valid values onto an output list.

Comment: `::` isn't type casting.

Comment: Has the book introduced list comprehensions yet?

Comment: @melpomene The book has introduced me to list comprehensions aye. Should I be using them to decimate the database for UTCTime values?

Comment: Yeah, a list comprehension is probably the most straightforward solution to this problem. BTW, you don't need to interact with `Data.Time` for this task.

Comment: @melpomene So, how do I go about using list comprehensions to complete this task? I'd imagine something like `[x | x <- database, ...]`?

Comment: @simpleigh Yeh, that's what the task might be asking me to do. There are other ways as @melpomene has described. But I think the task wants me to use folds, since the tasks are in a chapter regarding folds and their uses. It did demonstrate that I could assert types with `::` so it might have something to do with that.

Comment: @Poriferous For the record, the comprehension-based definition would be `filterDate items = [time | DbDate time <- items]`. This exploits that in list comprehensions, pattern failures (i.e. non-`DbDate` items) are silently skipped.

Comment: @FrerichRaabe That's very interesting! I didn't know that. But then, how can we create a generic filter function that can get values by type? For example, would it be possible to pass a type to the function so that it can get values of that type? I do notice that these getters/filters have similar behaviour/functionality. So, something like `filterBy TYPE items = [t | TYPE t <- items]` could be valid? Then I could call the function as `let m = filterBy DbDate database` which would return all the values of type `DbDate` from the `database`.

Comment: @Poriferous I don't think that generalization gets you very far, but you could define a function `Item -> Maybe UTCTime` via `f x = case x of DbDate t -> Just t; _ -> Nothing`. And then use `mapMaybes f` to get a function `[Item] -> [UTCTime]`. `mapMaybes` is from `Data.Maybe`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

OK, my Haskell-fu is extremely weak but I'm going to have a stab at an answer. You're looking to define a function that walks across a list and filters it. If the value is a `DbDate` then you return `<that value> : <output list>`, otherwise you return `<output list>`. By folding over the input you produce a filtered output. There's a relevant question at [How would you define map and filter using foldr in Haskell?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5726445/how-would-you-define-map-and-filter-using-foldr-in-haskell) which might explain this better.

This breaks down to something like:

```
filterFn :: Item -> [UTCTime] -> [UTCTime]
filterFn (DbDate x) xs = x:xs
filterFn _ xs = xs
```

(this might be a syntax fail). This function takes an item off our `[Item]` and pattern matches.

- If it matches `DbDate x` then `x` is a `UTCTime` and we append it to our input list.
- If it doesn't then we ignore it and return the input list unchanged.

We can then fold:

```
filterDate = foldr filterFn []
```

Does that get you to an answer?

Comment: Not quite because DbDate requires an argument before it can be used for pattern matching. The compiler complains about the lack of arguments to DbDate.

Comment: Try `filterFn (DbDate x) xs = x:xs` and `filterFn _ xs = xs`. Only two arguments must be used here, so parentheses are needed.

Comment: @chi I think that's more along the lines of what the compiler agrees with. I modified the filter function then I used `foldr filterDate [] database` which returns the time values as a list. It was more an issue as to how I 'fetch' the right types. My only concern here is that this function actually doesn't have the same type signature. From what I have, filterDate's type signature is `Item -> [UTCTime] -> [UTCTime]`.

Comment: @Poriferous are you sure? Using your definition of `Item` and my definitions of `filterFn` and `filterDate` above, `ghci` gives me the following type signature: `filterDate :: [Item] -> [UTCTime]` which is what we want.

Comment: Being a C++ programmer, I naturally renamed the `filterFn` functions to getters which helps me understand things a bit better. Thanks to you two I've been able to solve all tasks seamlessly. :-)

Answer (score 0):

Item is defined as a union type, which means it can be a `DbString`, a `DbNumber` or a `DbDate`.

```
data Item = DbString String
      | DbNumber Integer
      | DbDate UTCTime
      deriving (Eq, Ord, Show)
```

You can use [pattern matching](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Haskell/Pattern_matching) to get only the value you're interested in. You need to match on an item, check whether it is a `DbDate` and if that's the case extract the `UTCTime` instance it holds.

You said you want to use a [fold](https://wiki.haskell.org/Fold) so you need an accumulator where you can put the values you want to keep and a function to populate it.

```
filterDate items = foldl accumulate [] items
    where extractTime item = case item of DbDate time -> [time]
                                          _ -> []
          accumulate item accumulator = accumulator ++ (extractTime item)
```

In the code above you have `extractTime` that pattern matches over an item and either returns a list containing the time or it returns an empty list. The `accumulate` function just puts together the values you got from the previous steps (they're stored in `accumulator`) and the value you got applying `extractTime` to the current item.