# Pattern matching inside lambda

Tags: haskell, lambda, pattern-matching

I'm learning Haskell. This is a trivial example but I'd like to understand the concept why I can't use the pattern matching inside the lambda function in the following example (i.e., why does the filterfold' function run but filterfold' gives a runtime error):

```
-- Runs
filterfold' :: (a -> Bool) -> [a] -> [a]
filterfold' p zs = foldr (\y zs -> if (p y) then y:zs else zs) [] zs

-- Runtime error: Non-exhaustive patterns in lambda
filterfold :: (a -> Bool) -> [a] -> [a]
filterfold p (z:zs) = foldr (\y (z:zs) -> if (p y) then y:(z:zs) else (z:zs)) [] (z:zs)
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

you can use it but as the compiler tells you you are missing a case (when the input is `[]`)

See if you say `z:zs` it will try to match this pattern with the input-list - if you

- input `[1,2,3] = 1:[2,3]` you get `z=1` and `zs=[2,3]`
- but when input `[]` you cannot get a `z` and `zs` so that `z:zs = []` (technically they are based on different constructors of the list-datatype)

So at runtime it will not know how to handle this case/pattern when it sees `[]` and throw the exception.

if you look closely at your example you should see that you never actually use the parts anyway (meaning `z` or `zs` - you only use them as `z:zs` again) so I cannot tell you how to do it better

anyway you can use the `case` - expression inside of an lambda:

```
... = foldr (\ x zs -> case zs of
                         [] -> ...
                         z:zs -> ...
```

or you can use the [LambdaCase](https://prime.haskell.org/wiki/LambdaCase) extension to make it a bit shorter.

Comment: So, the zs from the filterfold function's argument is in scope but instead of using the 'z' from filterfold it tries to perform pattern matching locally inside the lambda?

Comment: yes the `z` and `zs` inside the lambda will be different ones (`foldr` will *provide* them)  - that's why you should not reuse parameter/argument names for lambda-arguments - you *introduce* those names with your lambda and will hide the once from the outer-scope - so if you want to (re)use the `z` and `zs` from the outer-scope in `filterfold` you should just rename it into `foldr (\y ys -> ...)` (or whatever name you like different from `p`, `z`, `zs` and `y` ;) )

Comment: but please note: if you don't actually need the second argument of function (the lambda) you are giving to `foldr` then you probably don't need the `foldr` in the first place as you are only acting on the `head` of the list if it's not-empty or defaulting to the second argument of `foldr`

Comment: Understand that filterfold' is a cleaner version than filterfold. This is just for a conceptual understanding. So, in filterfold' I could define for foldr the lambda function as (\y qs -> if (p y) then y:qs else qs) with different argument names. I understand that the y argument in the lambda will be the current element in the list 'zs'. But what is qs? Why is it same as the zs list?

Comment: you can think of the `qs` as the accumulator or state you pass around - so you start at the right end of your input list and replace the `[]` there with the second parameter to `foldr` (here '[]` too)  - then you take the last element `y` and `qs=[]` and compine those with your lambda into a new `qs` ... repeat that to your first element in the list

Comment: just look for tuturials/articles on list-fold - you fill find plenty

Comment: Thanks, Carsten! I also figured out how the lambda function  for foldr works (and what the arguments refer to) and posted it: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5726445/how-would-you-define-map-and-filter-using-foldr-in-haskell/38554918#38554918