# How to filter indexes in a list?

Tags: haskell, functional-programming

For example, if I have a list of

> [2,2,3,5,4,6]

and I filter for even numbers, I want to output the indexes of those numbers:

> [1,2,5,6]

I know about the `filter` function which return the elements. How can I get their indexes instead?
I have defined the fuction index which return the elements with their indexes as tuplets. Any hints how should I continue?

```
index x = [ n | n <- [ zip x [1..]]]
```

Comment: Duplicate of: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58952901/how-to-get-the-list-of-indexes-matching-a-predicate

Comment: Sorry, didn't find that one!

Comment: I might be able to solve this myself with the hints in the comments there

Comment: Not so much a "hint" from the comments on that question, but using [`findIndicies`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Data-List.html#v:findIndices): `findIndices even [2,2,3,5,4,6]` does exactly what you require.

Comment: I managad to create the indexed list, but now I don't know how to continue

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How would you define map and filter using foldr in Haskell?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5726445/how-would-you-define-map-and-filter-using-foldr-in-haskell)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code,

```
index x = [ n | n <- [ zip x [1..] ] ]
```

the `[ n | n <- [ e ]]` is  equivalent to `[ n | let n=e ]` is equivalent to `let n = e in [n]` or just `[e]`, i.e. `[zip x [1..]]`. It's not what you want.

The

```
index x = [ n | n <- ( zip x [1..] ) ]
```

on the other hand, is different. The parens are used for grouping, and as such are superfluous and can be omitted here. The code then is equivalent to `[ n | n <- e ]` which is equivalent to just `e` i.e.  `zip x [1..]`, which is a step closer.

You just need to deconstruct the `n`, which is a pair of an element and an index (constructed by `zip`), and include an index if the element is even, in the output list.

We deconstruct values by pattern matching.

A pair pattern is written `(a,b)`, or `(e,i)`, etc.

Answer (score 0):

First, you can give the index of a list using `zip`. From the list with index, we can `filter` the list that has a even value. After that we can extract the value.

```
-- Will be (Value, Index) tuple
withIndex :: [Int] -> [(Int, Int)]
withIndex x = zip x [1..]

main =
    print (
        map snd (
            filter
                (even . fst)
                (withIndex [2, 2, 3, 5, 4, 6])
        )
    )
```

https://ideone.com/GDmW6j