# What does ' mean/do at the end of function name in Haskell?

Tags: haskell, syntax

I started with Haskell a few days ago and I found some solution for my problem online, but I started to notice that some function has a symbol at the end of the function name.

What is the meaning?

An example could be

```
map'            :: (a -> b) -> [a] -> [b]
map' f []       = []
map' f (x:xs)   = foldr (\y ys -> (f y):ys) [] xs
```

[Source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5726445/how-would-you-define-map-and-filter-using-foldr-in-haskell)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The character `'` can be added to any identifier in Haskell, so `map'` is an identifier. In this context, [`'` is also called *"prime"*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime_%28symbol%29), so `map'` would be pronounciated "map prime" if you were to read it out loud.

The use stems from mathematics, where function variants (often their derivatives) have some kind of symbol attached to them, e.g.

| Function | Meaning |
| --- | --- |
| *f* | Original function |
| *f'* | Derivative of *f* |
| *f''* | Second derivative *f* |
| *f** | Some special variant of *f* (usually called *"f star"*) |
| *f̂* (f with ^) | Some other special variant, usually the Fourier transform of *f*, called *"f hat"*. |

In Haskell, the prime usually indicates either a

- strict variant (e.g. `foldl'`),
- a custom implementation (e.g. `map'` in your own code, as it conflicts with `Prelude.map`),
- a value derived from another one (e.g. `x' = go x`) or
- an internal function (an implementation detail inside a library)

Especially the third variant can be found often in `where` or `let` clauses. Naming is hard after all, and a single prime allows you to both show the origin of the value and remove the need to come up with a better name:

```hs
-- | 'pow x n' calculates 'x' to the power of 'n'. 
--    It uses the double-and-add method internally
pow :: Int -> Int -> Int
pow x 0 = 1
pow x 1 = x
pow x n
  | even n    = x' * x'      -- usage of 'pow x (n/2)' here
  | otherwise = x' * x' * x  -- use of both x' and x
 where   
   x'    = pow x (n `div` 2) -- x' stems from the original x
```

Note that you may have arbitrary many `'` in your identifier:

```
some'strange'example'don't'do'this :: Int
some'strange'example'don't'do'this = 12

foo'''''''''''''' = "please don't do this :)"
```

A single quote at the start of an identifier isn't allowed, as it would clash with a usual `Char`, though.

Comment: What, are you suggesting I should stop calling my variables `_፞''፞''፞'፞`?

Comment: @leftaroundabout Are... are those `ETHIOPIC COMBINING VOWEL LENGTH MARK`s? My terminal breaks on those :(

Answer (score 7):

The `'` is usually added to indicate that this is some *variant* of a function `map`. It's really just part of the name (it's a valid character).

In this example here `map` is already provided by `Prelude` so you'd have a name-conflict. So there is need for a different name and `map'` does the job without thinking too much.

Often `'` indicates that the function is **strict** (for example [`foldl'`](https://wiki.haskell.org/Foldr_Foldl_Foldl%27)) too.

Comment: Thanks, so I can call this function as `map'`. thanks and sorry for the stupid question

Comment: it's not a stupid question at all - some students associate this with some kind of derivative (especially students having a math background ;) ) - and most other languages don't allow the character for their identifiers so the confusion is very understandable

Comment: Yes agree, is a little bit different from the other language. Thanks to clarify this.